# Trim JSON fields, not working for nested JSON

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, json.net

I want to trim all string field in my JSON. I use to it own JSonConverter (code is below, Newtonsoft), which is added on MVC application start in global.asax. Everything go fine, if there is no nested JSON. If there is, nested JSON are not handled. Why? What should I change to fix it?

For example

```
{"Name":"    Jacek     ","Age" = "   10    "} working

{"Name":"  Jacek   ","Age"=" 10 "."Address":{"street":" Long "}} NOT working for street, but works for name and age.
```

My string converter string

```
public class MyStringConverter : JsonConverter
{
    public override bool CanConvert(Type objectType)
    {
        return objectType == typeof(string);
    }

    public override bool CanRead { get { return true; } }

    public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        var text = (string)reader.Value;

        return TrimInputField(text);
    }

    public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, object value, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        writer.WriteValue(value);
    }

    public string TrimInputField(string input)
    {
        if (false == string.IsNullOrEmpty(input))
        {
            input = input.Trim();

            var regex = new Regex(@"\s+");
            input = regex.Replace(input, " ");
        }

        return input;
    }
}
```

Comment: why not use the built-in serializer? I thing NewtonSoft provide a method that directly serialize your .net object...

Comment: This seems to [work fine for me](https://dotnetfiddle.net/A8xB2e).

Answer (score 1):

"," , not "." 
{"Name":"  Jacek   ","Age"=" 10 ", "Address":{"street":" Long "}}

Comment: Add explanation to your answer